# Коллайдер и рейкаст

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру на подобие My summer car. Проблема возникла с поршнями в блоке. Если поршень установить, то его уже невозможно снять, т.к. на блоке висит box collider, в который врезается рекайст, не доходя до поршня. А нужно, чтобы можно было и снять поршень, и взаимодействовать с блоком (взять и тд). Проблема точно в этом, если вытащить поршень из блока через инспектор, то поршень успешно снимется. mesh collider использовать не вариант, написано, мол non kinematic rigidbody не поддерживается, а kinematic мне не подойдёт. Все взаимодействия сделаны через рейкаст. Как быть? В my summer car это как-то обыграли.